# Specify Qt version with CMakeSettings.json in Linux machine

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, linker

I'm building a project with Visual Studio 2019 and CMake using a Linux machine. This is the configuration defined in the CMakeSettings.json

```
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "DEV_ROOT": "/home/user/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}",
      "CMAKE_ADDITIONAL_MODULES_DIR": "/home/user/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/cmake_modules",
      "CMAKE_OWN_MODULES_DIR": "/home/user/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/cmake_modules",
      "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "/opt/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/gcc_64"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Linux-GCC-Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "cmakeExecutable": "cmake",
  "remoteCopySourcesExclusionList": [
    ".vs",
    ".git",
    "out"
  ],
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [
    "linux_x64"
  ],
  "remoteMachineName": "${defaultRemoteMachineName}",
  "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/src",
  "remoteBuildRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/build/${name}",
  "remoteInstallRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/install/${name}",
  "remoteCopySources": true,
  "rsyncCommandArgs": "-t --delete --delete-excluded",
  "remoteCopyBuildOutput": false,
  "remoteCopySourcesMethod": "rsync",
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "ZMQ_ROOT",
      "value": "/opt/libzmq"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, in the `environments` section I define the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for using a custom Qt version.

The project is configured and then is built, but then I've an error on Qt when the project starts:

```
user@user:~/.vs/project/67f7c9a8-ca83-4b4b-8577-472524095d2d/out/build/Linux-GCC-Debug$ ./program
./program: symbol lookup error: ./program: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

I've performed a `ldd` command, and I've noticed that the Qt linked in the executable are not the same that I've defined in the project:

```
user@user:~/.vs/program/67f7c9a8-ca83-4b4b-8577-472524095d2d/out/build/Linux-GCC-Debug$ ldd ./program
        ...
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f890842e000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f8907d93000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f890784a000)
        libPocoFoundation.so.51 => /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.51 (0x00007f8907643000)
        ...
        libQt5Sql.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f8907007000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8906e46000)
        libPocoNetSSL.so.71 => /opt/pocolib/lib/libPocoNetSSL.so.71 (0x00007f8906def000)
        ...
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f8905c01000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8905be3000)
        ...
```

As you can see, the libQtXXX libraries are the default ones installed with the package manager.

How can I fix this and use the Qt that I've defined in the `CMakeSettings.json`?

Comment: try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/gcc_64/lib ldd ./program`

Comment: When configure the project, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` has a precedence over system directory, so CMake correctly configures the project. But the path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` is constructed by the dynamic loader by using RPATH mechanism. Because you use pthread library, which is located at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0`, the directory `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is already in RPATH. It could be very tricky to tell dynamic loader to prefer your custom directory to the system one. BTW, in such cases CMake usually emits a warning like "Cannot construct safe RPATH".